# Make Polygon objects from geojson

Tags: python, geometry, polygon, geojson, shapely

I have geojson files that can have x amount of polygons so I have a for loop that goes through the file and adds the coords of each polygon to an array. Now i'm trying to index the array when making Polygon objects.

```
    def check_overlap():
    geom = []
    for j in range(int(get_polygon_count())):
        for i, feature in enumerate(data['features'][j+1:]):
            geom.append(feature['geometry']['coordinates'])
    value1 = geom[0]
    polygon1 = Polygon(value1)
    #polygon2 = Polygon(geom[1])
    print(polygon1)
    print(geom[1])
    #print(polygon1.intersects(polygon2))
```

The error I get is ValueError: A LinenearRing must have at least 3 coordinate tuples

Comment: Improve the formatting of the code (indentation), please.

Comment: The indentation is fine the loops work how I want them to its the creation of the Polygon object which is not working. @blunova

Comment: The indentation is not fine. Look at the very first line, please.

Comment: But where is LinenearRing?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

It's bit of a guesswork, but the way that `geom` list gets filled and later indexed makes `Polygon()` to fail with every GeoJSON Polygon as structures are different.

[GeoJSON polygon](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7946#appendix-A.3):

> Coordinates of a Polygon are an array of linear ring (see    Section
> 3.1.6) coordinate arrays.  The first element in the array    represents the exterior ring.  Any subsequent elements represent
> interior rings (or holes).

If structure in `geom[x]` happens to be GeoJSON Polygon with no holes, it looks something like this :

```
[[[100.0, 0.0], [101.0, 0.0], [101.0, 1.0], [100.0, 1.0], [100.0, 0.0]]]
```

[Shapely `Polygon()`](https://shapely.readthedocs.io/en/stable/manual.html#polygons):

> takes two positional parameters. The first is an ordered sequence of
> `(x, y[, z])` point tuples and is treated exactly as in the LinearRing
> case. The second is an optional unordered sequence of ring-like
> sequences specifying the interior boundaries or “holes” of the
> feature.

What `Polygon()` expects is the first element of GeoJSON Polygon, optionally followed by holes:

```py
geom = []
geom.append([[[100.0, 0.0], [101.0, 0.0], [101.0, 1.0], [100.0, 1.0], [100.0, 0.0]]])
geom[0]
# [[[100.0, 0.0], [101.0, 0.0], [101.0, 1.0], [100.0, 1.0], [100.0, 0.0]]]
Polygon(geom[0]).wkt
# ValueError: A LinearRing must have at least 3 coordinate tuples

geom[0][0]
# [[100.0, 0.0], [101.0, 0.0], [101.0, 1.0], [100.0, 1.0], [100.0, 0.0]]
Polygon(geom[0][0]).wkt
# 'POLYGON ((100 0, 101 0, 101 1, 100 1, 100 0))'
```

Though I'd just load the whole thing into GeoPandas.